# Getting around undefined symbol: _strnicmp

Tags: python, c, linux, windows, shared-libraries

I have a library which is a python wrapper for a C/C++ library, which needs to be imported to Python in Linux. Let's call the library `abc.so`. This library is dependent on another C/C++ library: `xyz`. Both these libraries used to have/have facilities that are dependent on Windows, Borland compiler or similar compilers. I am able to successfully build `abc.so`, after fixing some of the windows compiler related issues. However, I cannot import it to my python code. I receive the error:

> ImportError: /usr/local/lib/abc.so: undefined symbol: _strnicmp

or a variant of this. I tried various import methods involving packages like `ctpes`, `os`, `sys` and flags like `RTLD_LAZY`, `RTLD_GLOBAL`, `RTLD_NOW` under the assumption that the method of import will fix this problem. However, none of them worked. This answer: [undefined reference to stricmp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5919134/4834108) (and the comment above) suggests that `strnicmp` should be replaced. It also points out that this is a link time error. However, I have not been able to identify part of these libraries expecting an implementation of `strnicmp`. What would be a good approach to find the source of this issue? Also, should I be trying some alternative path to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`stricmp()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stricmp-wcsicmp?view=msvc-170) and [`strnicmp()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strnicmp-wcsnicmp?view=msvc-170) functions are specific to Windows.

POSIX (Linux) uses the `<strings.h>` header and [`strcasecmp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html) and `strncasecmp()`.

You can write a simple cover function or change the calls via a macro.  For the cover function, you'd want to use appropriate conditional compilation (`#ifdef SOMETHING` / `#endif` — or maybe `#ifndef SOMETHING` / `#endif`).  You might use an inline function if it only appears in one file.  If it appears in many files, you may want a regular function, even though it's a smidgeon less efficient.  If there's a convenient header included by all the files that you can modify to add (conditionally) the `static inline` function definition, that can work well — it's also about the only time you normally add a function body to a header file.

```
static inline int strnicmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t len)
{
    return strncasecmp(s1, s2, len);
}
```

or

```
#undef strnicmp
#define strnicmp(s1, s2, len) strncasecmp(s1, s2, len)
```

Comment: So is this just a matter of tracking down `strnicmp` in the source files for these libraries?

Comment: Mostly — but you'll want to do it automatically rather than editing many files.  For example, you might add the macro or `static inline` function definition to one header that's included by all the files afflicted.

Comment: This technique (I used conditional compilation) worked. Thank you.